# Ethereum 2.0 - can 32 ether staking limit become lesser?

Tags: eth-2.0

As we all know, there is a 32 ether requirement to become a full validator for the incoming PoS update. For now, the ethereum 2.0 is still in experimental stage and there is a lot of work to perform the full migration. If something happens in the future (for example ethereum price will grow), is it possible for devs to change the limit to less, for example 1 ether? Or is the value 32 rigid, hard coded and it will never be changed since they announced ethereum 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, to become a validator 32eth are needed and you need to send them to [this smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa#code). But if you look at it, you can see the threshold to accept a transaction to this smart contract is 1eth:

```
require(msg.value >= 1 ether, "DepositContract: deposit value too low");
```

So people can send less than 32eth to this smart contract (and [they do](https://etherscan.io/txsBeaconDeposit)). But the sum of the transaction you make to this smart contract must be at least 32eth to be eligible to be placed in the activation queue. That is what the specifications [states](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#is_eligible_for_activation_queue).

So if you want to modify this threshold you a fork should be done. (There will be also be a need to change several parameters such as the `EJECTION_BALANCE` which [is for now](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#is_eligible_for_activation_queue) at 16eth)